# Simple class exercise using the "this" pointer

Tags: c++, algorithm, classes

This is my solution for an exercise from a book.  It's a simple `Golf` class with member variables `fullname` and `handicap`. The constructor sets the variables to the provided name and handicap using values passed as arguments. The `setgolf()` function solicits name and handicap from user, creates a temporary `Golf` object and assigns it to the invoking object.

Is this a proper solution? I'm particularly interested in the `setgolf()` method.

**golf.h:**

```
#include <string>

class Golf
{
    private:
        std::string fullname;
        int handicap;
    public:
        Golf();
        Golf(const std::string name, int hc);
        int setgolf();
        void sethandicap(int hc);
        void showgolf();
};
```

**golf.cpp:**

```
#include "golf.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

Golf::Golf(const std::string name, int hc)
{
    fullname = name;
    handicap = hc;
}

int Golf::setgolf()
{
    std::string name;
    int hc;
    std::cout << "Enter the name: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    if (name == "")
        return 0;
    std::cout << "Enter the handicap: ";
    std::cin >> hc;
    *this = Golf(name, hc);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You're not using `<cstring>` specifically in your implementation, so remove it.
- If you're not defining `sethandicap()` anywhere, remove the declaration.
- The constructor is only initializing data members, so it can be an [initializer list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html):

  ```
  Golf::Golf(std::string name, int hc) : fullname(name), handicap(hc) {}
  ```
- Although I agree with @Anton Golov about `setgolf()`, I'll address some things in it anyway:

  ```
  std::cout << "Enter the name: ";
  std::string name;        // put declaration here to maintain a closer scope
  getline(std::cin, name); // don't forget the "std::"

  if (name.empty()) return 0; // empty() is more readable than ""

  std::cout << "Enter the handicap: ";
  std::cin.ignore(); // getline() is used prior, so add this
  int hc;            // put declaration here to maintain a closer scope
  std::cin >> hc;
  ```

Comment: Setters need not break encapsulation; there's no reason the class interface shouldn't have some property that the user may change the value of.  For instance, if we have a lexer class, setting the current line number may be a valid operation.

Comment: @AntonGolov: Okay.  I suppose I'm still unsure about what exactly breaks encapsulation and what doesn't.  Many different contradictions, it seems.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to say whether the solution is proper when there isn't a problem to solve.  How a class should be designed depends on how it will be used; a class in isolation is hard to judge.  Even if you want to focus on some specific aspect, try to fit it into the context of a larger problem.

Back to the code: I suspect `showgolf` should be a `const` function.  I don't see why printing a `Golf` would change it.  You probably also meant to pass your constructor a `const std::string&`.  Finally, are you sure a `showgolf` member function is really what you want -- why not an `operator<<` overload?

Moving on to the `Golf::setgolf` function specifically, I don't think such a function is meaningful.  An `operator>>` overload or a free `queryGolf` function sound significantly more sensible to me.  More specifically, the usage:

```
Golf golf;
golf.setgolf();
```

Why not just `auto golf = queryGolf();`?  It's simpler, it means you can't forget to check whether things succeeded, and given `setGolf`'s implementation it is likely to be just as efficient.

Speaking of checking whether things succeeded, why not throw an exception if the input is invalid?  There are valid reasons, but it's certainly a solution you should consider.  (By the way, if my previous solution sounded bad due to the need for exceptions, have no fear: `boost::optional` fits the use-case very well.)

And, in a similar vein: it sounds like you're trying to prevent the creation of invalid `Golf`s.  However, your default constructor does exactly that.  Are you sure default-construction is more valuable than guaranteed validity?  Again, depending on what you do with the class, the answer varies.

All in all, I'd suggest dropping `showgolf` and writing:

```
Golf promptGolf() {
    Golf golf;
    // read into fullname and handicap.  promptGolf may be a friend.
    if (/* golf is not valid, std::cin died, etc. */)
        throw TerribleError{};
    return golf;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Lose the `private`, `class` members are private by default.
- `setGolf()`: Instead of returning 1 or 0, you can apply *exceptions management* here. Also, you're doing double jobs by `*this = Golf(name, hc);`. You call a constructor that creates an instance of `Golf` and then assign that instance to `*this` when you don't even have an assignment operator defined. Don't worry, a default version is already generated.

  You can  fix that by doing this:

  ```
  this->fullname = name;
  this->handicap = hc;
  ```

Comment: I think explicitly making members `private` just makes it a bit clearer and doesn't really have any drawbacks.

Comment: @Tharwen: Agreed.  I think it's also helpful in case you have both `public` and `private` functions.